# Reg Exp for URL in HAProxy

Tags: routing, haproxy, regex, url

I'm trying to build a reg exp for haproxy that will match the second URL and direct it to a different acl than the first:

```
mysite.com/path/
mysite.com/path/something_random
```

The issue is that my first reg exp matches both urls above when it should only match the second one. I can't find more documentation on haproxy regex's format either so I'm not even sure where to reference the reg exp format I should be using for matching. Can reg exp pro's help me I'm new to this thanks.

```
 acl filebrowser_route path_reg ^/path/.*
 acl filebrowser url_beg /path
```

Comment: It looks to me like both your ACLs will match both URLs. If the first URL is ONLY ever going to be `mysite.com/path/`, then the ACL should be `acl filebrowser path /path/`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to construct two regex's that are mutually exclusive: only one can be true at a time:

How about if you make the second item be a regex like:

```
^/path[^/]
```

The `[^/]` means "any character that is not /".

Here are three URLs that are mutually exclusive:

```
acl fb1 path_reg ^/path$          # Just /path
acl fb2 path_reg ^/path/$         # Just /path/
acl fb3 path_reg ^/path/..*$      # /path/ plus at least 1 character
```

Comment: Really great clear examples on the regex. Thanks this works.

Comment: I just see the answer from TomOnTime and follow it. I think the correct regex for "any character that is not /" should be: ^/path[^/]
^ but not ~